# Shiny table formatting

Tags: r, shiny, dt, formattable

I am new to Shiny and have a basic shiny app using mtcars. I have multiple tabs with some input dropdowns and presenting the output as DT tables. This is all working fine, but I would now like to use some formatting like formattable. Some of the formatting I would like to include is basic percentage, decimal. Also, I would like to add some cell based highlighting. I have tried multiple formatting functions without any luck. I have added functions within the server side output, but I can not get the right combination. Below is my Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("mtcars"),

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  selectInput("cyl", 
              "cyl:",
              c(unique(as.character(mtcars$cyl)))), 

    selectInput("gear",
                "gear:",
                c("All",
                  unique(as.character(mtcars$gear)))), width=2),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("Summary", DT::dataTableOutput("Summary")),
        tabPanel("Detail", DT::dataTableOutput("Detail"))))))
    server <- function(input, output) {

    output$Detail <- renderDataTable(datatable({
       data <- mtcars
         if (input$cyl != "All") {
             data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
             }
         if (input$gear != "All") {
             data <- data[data$gear == input$gear,]
             }
         data
         }))

    output$Summary <- renderDataTable({

    mtcars %>% 
      filter(cyl==input$cyl)  %>% 
      group_by(gear) %>%
      summarise(mpg = median(mpg), 
                count = n())  %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(desc(count))
    })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far with `formattable`, but you should be able to use it with `DT` in your shiny app.

Here is a quick example you can try. This makes the `mpg` column a percentage. Also, if colors the `count` column a shade of green.

Other [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html) are available for other options with `formattable` package.

```
output$Summary <- renderDataTable({
  my_data <- mtcars %>% 
    filter(cyl==input$cyl)  %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(mpg = median(mpg), 
              count = n())  %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(desc(count))

  # Make percent, for example
  my_data$mpg <- percent(my_data$mpg)

  # Return formattable datatable
  return(
    as.datatable(
      formattable(
        my_data,
        list(
          count = color_tile("transparent", "green")
        )
      )
    )
  )
})
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete Ben's answer, even if you say you want to use `formattable`, I think there are enough options in `DT` to customize the tables the way you want.

Here's your example (randomly customized since you didn't specify the formatting of the cells):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("mtcars"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("cyl", 
                  "cyl:",
                  c(unique(as.character(mtcars$cyl)))), 

      selectInput("gear",
                  "gear:",
                  c("All",
                    unique(as.character(mtcars$gear)))), width=2),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("Summary", DT::dataTableOutput("Summary")),
        tabPanel("Detail", DT::dataTableOutput("Detail"))))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Detail <- renderDataTable(datatable({
    data <- mtcars
    if (input$cyl != "All") {
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$gear != "All") {
      data <- data[data$gear == input$gear,]
    }
    data
  }))

  output$Summary <- renderDataTable({

    your_data <- mtcars %>% 
      filter(cyl==input$cyl)  %>% 
      group_by(gear) %>%
      summarise(mpg = median(mpg), 
                count = n())  %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(desc(count))

    datatable(your_data) %>%
      formatPercentage(columns = c("mpg", "gear")) %>%
      formatRound(columns = c("count"), digits = 3) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "mpg",
                  valueColumns = "gear", 
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(3, 4, 5), c("red", "blue", "green")))
  })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) for more details, and [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) for several examples of color-styling.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for and provided a solution to begin adding custom formatting.

Comment: @Rambo8198 you're welcome, don't forget to upvote the answers and to mark as "answer" (just below the voting arrows) the one that solved your problem